# Javascript. What is the difference between closures and dynamic 'this' binding practically speaking?

Tags: javascript

I think that there is a significant amount of overlap between what you can achieve with closures and what you can achieve with constructors in Javascript - some slight differences in the API to the different structures notwithstanding.

This code:

```
function Animal1(name) {
    this.name = name;
};
var x = new Animal1('x');
console.log(x.name); // x
```

Seems functionally quite similar to this code:

```
function Animal2(name) {
    var name = name;
    var getName = function() {return name;};
    return {name: getName};
}
var y = Animal2('y');
console.log(y.name()); // y
```

Except that x gets assigned a `__proto__` property. If you weren't going to use prototypal inheritance in your code, how would you choose between closures and constructors such as above?

i.e. which takes more memory? which is more efficient? are there other things to consider? etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Animal2(name) {
    var name = name;
    var getName = function() {return name;};
    return {name: getName};
}
var y = Animal2('y');
console.log(y.name()); // y
```

In the preceding code the getName function is generated every time Animal2 is called.  In this case of course it's trivial but this method both requires more memory and is slower.  A benefit of this method can be that it allows you a degree of encapsulation as you can have private variables shared between functions that are not exposed.

Take a look at the following for more information:
https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript

Comment: Regarding memory - I wouldn't be at all surprised if modern JS engines used the same "copy" of the function for each object created.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Do you have any evidence or source for that? Right now this sounds just like speculation, would be very interesting to see if they did that.

Comment: Thanks. So the benefit of a closure is that you can have private variables that you would otherwise not be able to have using constructors?

Comment: Private variables that can be accessed by the functions you return yes.

Comment: From the link it looks like closures impact performance compared to constructors. Thanks for that link

Comment: @Chips_100 [Here's one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/BbvL5qFG_uc).

Comment: Well, as of a document last updated February 3, 2016 on the Google developer site under the "Defining class methods" heading:  "The following is inefficient, as each time a instance of baz.Bar is constructed, a new function and closure is created for foo:".